# When to use : and = in javascript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, function, object, syntax

I have these code snippet.

```
 const initialAuthState = {
  isAuthenticated:false
};
```

and

```
function login(state){
      state.isAuthenticated=true;
    }
```

How do I know when to use '=' and when to use ':' in javascript?

Comment: See [Object_initializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) and [Assignment (=)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment)

Comment: The first set of curly braces is an object literal, since it is after an assignment. The second set is a block which defines the body of the `login` function, which contains an assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`=` inside a function or code block (like inside an `if`/`else`/`for`/`while` etc.), `:` inside of objects.